# Remove a folder for downloadable files to reduce the Akeeba backup file

Tags: joomla-3.x, akeebabackup, backups

i have a folder named "download" in public-Html folder. all downloadable files on my site, is in it. 
when i backup my site with Akeebabackup, this folder makes my backup file Biiiig.
what should i do if i don't this folder being contained in my Akeebabackup file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In akeeba backup component there is an option to exclude the files or folders which you don't want.

Go to the akeeba backup setting **Files and Directories Exclusion**, exclude the folder which you don't want and then run the backup.

And for more info you can read this: [Exclude data from the backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation/exclude-data-from-backup.html)

[Here](https://www.akeebabackup.com/videos/1212-akeeba-backup-core/1621-abtc07-excluding-large-files.html) is a video example.

Answer (score 4):

In your Joomla admin panel, go to the

- Akeeba Backup component page
- Then click "**Files and Directories Exclusion**"
- Then select the directory you wish to exclude by clicking the "**X**" button

[image]

Hope this helps